# What is the best approach to use Retrofit and Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit2, android-room, android-jetpack

I have a question regarding the process of storing data from the network.
I am using retrofit to retrieve data from the network, and Room to insert and retrieve from local storage (with PagedListAdapters and DataSource.Factorys).

**My first question is:** Should I save all the data from the network and use Room to store it all and request new data when the item does not exist in local database, our there is another way?

**My second question is:** How can I do pagination with retrofit and use PagedList.BoundaryCall and PagedListAdapter at the same time

I have this project in GitHub ( https://github.com/JosePedroNobre/jetpack-Product-Hunter ), if you want to take a look, specially in the **ui/adapters** package and in the **data/NetworkBoundResources**

I research a lot about this, and did not find anything that answer my question, if someone please helped me I would be grateful